# How to add an independent select all checkbox to Ant design table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I need to implement a custom table component in react js using the ant design. I want to have a checkbox for selecting all rows in a table. Just like the checkbox that is available in the ant table header, I want to control row selection. Any help?

Comment: Please follow this example [Custom Selection](https://ant.design/components/table#components-table-demo-row-selection-custom)

Comment: This example only helps to customize the table's own checkbox. However, I want to implement a checkbox that can do the same job. @MuhammadNoumanRafique

Comment: I'm not sure about your exact requirement but look like you have a checkbox outside outside the table wants to control the table selection using that checkbox. You can use `rowSelection` table prop to control the selection. You need to `selectedRowKeys` and `onChange` prop of `rowSelection`.